# Linq IList<T> hide data and bind to gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

this is window form, at the CardDto contain a list of item, when checkbox active is check how i not show out the item is not active?

```
private void BindCardRecord(IList<CardDto> cardDto)
{

   if (chkSearch_NonActive.Checked)
   {
      cardDto.Where(p => p.IsActive == false);
   }

    dgvSearchResult.DataSource = cardDto.ListToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to remove the inactive items before setting the datasource?

Comment: my isActive = true, when the checkbox non active is checked i want to kick all the isActive = true item

Comment: `cardDto.Where(p => p.IsActive == false);` isn't actually doing anything here. You need to assign the result of the function to a new variable (which will be an `IEnumerable<CardDto>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "kick" you mean "not show"

```
private void BindCardRecord(IList<CardDto> cardDto)
{

   if (chkSearch_NonActive.Checked)
   {
      var newList = cardDto.Where(p => p.IsActive == false).ToList();
      dgvSearchResult.DataSource = newList.ListToDataTable();
   }
}
```

Comment: var newList how to declare at above, because still has other condition